# jVectorMap - Drill-down map - custom background

Tags: javascript, jvectormap

I'm using drill-down map from jVectorMap and I'm trying to set custom background color to second layer of the map. To customize main level, I use "main" parameter, but I don't know how to expand this to lower levels of the map.
Thanks in advance,
Maciej