# JVectorMap Multimap drill down has different style when drilled down, how can I change this style as well?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, multimap, jvectormap

This question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31373458/jvectormap-drill-down-map-custom-background) as well maybe a year ago, but no answer was provided. I'd like to know how I can make the "drilled-down" map have the same style and background as my main map.

```
var regionStyling9 = {                  // This style is set to the main map's regionStyle
        initial: {
            fill: '#E9E9E9',
            stroke: '#505050',
            "fill-opacity": 1,
            "stroke-width": 1,
            "stroke-opacity": 1
        },
        hover: { fill: "#4DB870" }
    };

    $(function() {
        new jvm.MultiMap({
            container: $('#Chart9Map'),
            maxLevel: 1,
            main: {
                map: 'us_aea_en',
                backgroundColor: '#fff',
                regionStyle: regionStyling9,     // Here I set the top level style to the main map                    
                series: {
                    regions: [{ values: stateMapData, scale: ['#cce2ec', '#006593'], normalizeFunction: 'polynomial' }]
                }
            },
            mapUrlByCode: function(code, multiMap) {
                return '../Scripts/JVectorMap/jquery-jvectormap-data-' +
                    code.toLowerCase() +
                    '-' +
                    multiMap.defaultProjection +
                    '-en.js';
            }
        });
    });
```

How can I affect the style of the secondary chart like I did for the main chart?

According to the [jVectorMap MultiMap Documentation](http://jvectormap.com/documentation/javascript-api/jvm-multimap/), there is only config for the main map, no other object for the drill down maps...

Answer (score 2):

I know what you mean, I also could not find this info. It is very strange the library doesnt handle this. Its such a well produced package, yet seems to me missing some basics.
Assuming you arent using the free version, the license says you are allowed to modify the code.

Open up the jquery-jvectormap.js file (prettify it is needed).
At the bottom you'll see the lines:

```
   currentMap.params.container.hide(), that.maps[name] ? that.maps[name].params.container.show() : that.addMap(name, {
        map: name,
        multiMapLevel: currentMap.params.multiMapLevel + 1
    }), that.history.push(that.maps[name]), that.backButton.show()
```

Change this so settings from the main map are passed down to the children (so just add the 3 extra lines):

```
   currentMap.params.container.hide(), that.maps[name] ? that.maps[name].params.container.show() : that.addMap(name, {
        backgroundColor: that.params.main.backgroundColor,
        series: that.params.main.series,
        onRegionTipShow: that.params.main.onRegionTipShow,
        map: name,
        multiMapLevel: currentMap.params.multiMapLevel + 1
```

Comment: If you add regionStyle: that.params.main.regionStyle, you can get the granular styling as well.